# SocketTimeoutException after four requests to local bitcoind

Tags: java, htmlunit, bitcoind

I want to connect to bitcoind using java. My plan is to use htmlunit and gson. Right now I can complete a single request successfully. However, I can not do more than exactly *four* subsequent requests due to a SocketTimeoutException being thrown at the fifth request.

I tried:

- Waiting between requests. (No effect visible)
- Forcing a failing http status code e.g. by requesting `getinfoo` instead of `getinfo`. (I do *not* get the timeout after four failing requests)

Any help or comment is appreciated!

```
package test;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpMethod;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequest;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);

        // http://[bitcoind-user]:[password]@localhost:[bitcoind-port]
        String baseUrl = "http://admin:admin@localhost:8332/";

        client.getOptions().setTimeout(2000);
        while (true) {
            try {
                WebRequest req = new WebRequest(new URL(baseUrl));
                req.setAdditionalHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                req.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);

                JSONRequestBody body = new JSONRequestBody();
                body.setMethod("getinfo");
                req.setRequestBody(new Gson().toJson(body, JSONRequestBody.class));

                client.getPage(req);
                client.closeAllWindows();

                System.out.println("ok. (No Exception)");

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException tex) {
                System.out.println("not ok: SocketTimeoutException");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("not ok: IOException");
            } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException hex) {
                System.out.println("not ok: FailingHttpStatusCodeException");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(EDIT:)

Removing the `.setTimeout(2000)` did not help as well. Measuring the time for each request shows that they are quite quick:

```
ok. (No Exception)             Timer:  1.161 seconds
ok. (No Exception)             Timer:  0.112 seconds
ok. (No Exception)             Timer:  0.115 seconds
ok. (No Exception)             Timer:  0.075 seconds
not ok: SocketTimeoutException Timer: 90.119 seconds
not ok: SocketTimeoutException Timer: 90.145 seconds
not ok: SocketTimeoutException Timer: 90.134 seconds
```

Repeating same request multiple times in the terminal using `curl` took always less than one second so `bitcoind` should not be causing the problems.

Comment: It seems there is a bug in the 2.14 release at least. I could get my script working on 2.10 and 2.15...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try removing this line:

```
client.getOptions().setTimeout(2000);
```

If the client takes 2 or more seconds to process the fifth request it will obviously fail with a timeout exception.

Secondly, make sure you disable JavaScript if you don't really need it, as it can take more than 2 seconds to process too.

Comment: I have disabled JS and removed `setTimeout`. Yet, the same behavior is still observable.